# C++ how to know if number ends with some bit pattern

Tags: c++, bit

I want to know if a number ends with some predefined bit patterns.

for example
i want to know if a number N end with B

where, N is any number 
and B is also any number

for example

```
if N = 01011100 
  B = 100 then this C++ function should return 1 here in this case 1

if N = 01011100
  B = 101 then this function should return 0
```

:)

Comment: hint: search for *bitwise operations C++*, you should be able to do this using a very simple operation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first case:

```
unsigned n = 0x5C;
unsigned m = 0x7; // "mask"
unsigned b = 0x4;
if ((n & m)==b) {
  ...do something...
}
```

Here's how it works:

```
01011100  n
00000111  m
00000100  n & m  (bitand operator)
00000100  b
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know number of bits in B, then you need to build a pattern with this number of bits as 1. Supposing int has 32 bits on your system:

```
unsigned int mask = 0xFFFFFFFF >> (32 - numberOfBitsInB);
if (N & mask == B)
    printf("%d ends with %d\n", N, B);
else
  printf("Nope");
```

You can also compute number of bits in B via:

```
int tmpB = B;
int numberOfBitsInB = 0;
while (tmpB)
{
    numberOfBitsInB++;
    tmpB >>= 1;
}
```

Comment: Your mask computation code only works if the 'leftmost' bit in B is 1, eg. if you want to match against pattern `00101`, it does not return 5.  This might be OK since the question says that B should be a number (implicating that the highest bit is 1).

Comment: @ferdinand: true. In fact highest bit must be 1, or you must know the length of B in bits and just use the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int mask = ~0 >> (sizeof(unsigned int) * 8 - num_bits_in_B);

if (N & Bitmask == B)
  printf("%d ends with %d\n", N, B);
else
  printf("Nope");
```

Use the method suggested by @Benoit above to compute the number of bits in B.

Comment: Your test fails: `0x111 & 0x100 = 0x100`

Comment: (-1) `N & B == B` clearly doesn't do what the OP is asking (does '101' end with '100'?)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate a mask for any length bit pattern. Here is a C example. This would prevent you from having to hardcode 0x7 if you would like to check for more than 3 bits matching.

```
bool bitPattern(int N, int B)
{
    int shift = 0;
    int mask = 0x0;
    while(B >> shift++ > 0) mask |= 0x01 << shift-1;
    return  (N & mask) == B;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("01011100 ends with 100 ? %s\n", bitPattern(0x5C, 0x04) ? "Yes" : "No");
    printf("01011100 ends with 101 ? %s\n", bitPattern(0x5C, 0x05) ? "Yes" : "No");
}
```